# Custom Dask scheduler vs. Client

Tags: python, dask, xgboost, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I want to run Dask tasks on a custom scheduler similar to how Dask on Ray works.

Currently, I am using Dask's config to specify the scheduler:

```py
dask.config.set(scheduler=my_custom_scheduler)
```

This approach is working well with simple Dask dataframe operations such as this one:

```py
d_arr = da.from_array(np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(256, 256)))
print(d_arr.mean().compute())
```

However, anything which requires a Dask client, for example, XGBoost training, does not use the custom scheduler.

```py
dask.config.set(scheduler=my_custom_scheduler)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = dask.distributed.Client()

    # X and y must be Dask dataframes or arrays
    num_obs = 1e5
    num_features = 20
    X = da.random.random(size=(num_obs, num_features), chunks=(1000, num_features))
    y = da.random.random(size=(num_obs, 1), chunks=(1000, 1))

    dtrain = xgb.dask.DaskDMatrix(client, X, y)

    output = xgb.dask.train(
        client,
        {"verbosity": 2, "tree_method": "hist", "objective": "reg:squarederror"},
        dtrain,
        num_boost_round=4,
        evals=[(dtrain, "train")],
    )
```

This isn't a big surprise. The requirement for using a client with XGBoost forces me to somehow point the Dask Client to the `my_custom_scheduler` function, however, I could not find any way to do so.

Unfortunately, Dask's understanding of a Client, Scheduler, and Cluster is very coupled, making it not possible to simply drop in a scheduler replacement.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track in your understanding here. :)

`client` is tied to the distributed scheduler.

In Dask, a scheduler replacement generally means you can use the "dask collections" like Delayed, Array, or DataFrame with your own scheduler.

However, the [xgboost-dask integration](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/dask.html) is an integration with the distributed scheduler.

So, in your case, you would need an xgboost integration with *your custom scheduler*, does that make sense? For example, you mentioned Dask-on-Ray -- there is an [`xgboost-ray`](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-more-libs/xgboost-ray.html#distributed-xgboost-on-ray) backend, which allows you to use the Ray scheduler with xgboost and dask collections.